# Utilizar o Geocoder para retornar o endereço do aparelho

Tags: react-native

Quero colocar na minha aplicação um botão que ao ser apertado retorne o endereço atual do celular.

A latitude e longitude estou conseguindo retornar corretamente, e para converter estes dados em um endereço cheguei a biblioteca [react-native-geocoder](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder#install).

Meu código atual está assim:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoder';
 // 0.4.8

class GeolocationExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      error: null,
    };
  }
  
  refresh = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
  };

  render() {
    Geocoder.geocodePosition(this.state.latitude,this.state.longitude)
    return (
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
        <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
        
        {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
         <Button
          style={{ marginTop: 30 }}
          onPress={() => { this.refresh(); }}
          title="Refresh"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default GeolocationExample;
```

Pelo que entendi em `Geocoder.geocodePosition(this.state.latitude,this.state.longitude)` estaria retornando o endereço, porém não entendi como obter estes dados a partir dali.

O código no Snack: https://snack.expo.io/rJhYwaG2Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Geocoder.geocodePosition` retorna uma Promise, então você deve capturar o endereço com `.then`. Ex:

`Geocoder.geocodePosition(coords)
  .then(res => { this.setState({address: res[0].formatedAddress} ); console.log(res[0].formattedAddress)} )`

Comment: Mas e depois? Pois ai ele termina de capturar mas ainda não consigo retornar estes

Comment: Você pode dar um setState do resultado pois a chamada ao geocode é assíncrona. Depois você pode utilizar o state para mostrar o resultado. O formattedAdress é uma das propriedades do resultado. Você pode consultar na documentação do geocode e capturar a propriedade desejada.

Comment: Tentei fazer seguindo o que falou mas não está retornado o endereço, se puder dar uma ajuda abri uma pergunta sobre o código que escrevi: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248717/problemas-ao-retornar-o-endere%C3%A7o-atrav%C3%A9s-da-geolocaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o