# Problemas ao retornar o endereço através da geolocalização

Tags: react-native

Estou tentando utilizar a biblioteca [react-native-geocoder](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder) para retornar o endereço através da latitude e longitude do aparelho.

Através de resposta a [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243402/utilizar-o-geocoder-para-retornar-o-endere%C3%A7o-do-aparelho) e mais alguma pesquisa, cheguei a este [código](https://snack.expo.io/rykQYjipZ):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
  AppRegistry, 
  View, 
  Text
} from 'react-native';
import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoder'; // 0.5.0

Geocoder.apiKey = 'AIzaSyDtQ0zsYr1c_V7UmlHFekeFIGM2nDwnDEA';

export default class testeGeocoder extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      place: 'Localizando endereço...',
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );

    Geocoder.geocodePosition({ lat: this.state.latitude, long: this.state.longitude})
      .then(res => {
          this.setState({
              place: res[0].formatedAddress
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            this.setState({ error: error.message })
          });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
        <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.place.toString()}</Text>
        {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('testeGeocoder', () => testeGeocoder);
```

Porém este me retorna a latitude e longitude corretas, mas fica `Localizando endereço...` e nunca retorna.

Onde estou errando?

Comment: primeira coisa, a posicao esta sendo retornada corretamente?em caso afirmativo tenta colocar um `catch` na chamada de `geocodePosition` pelo menis assim aho que vai ter uma explicacao melhor do erro

Comment: Estive acompanhando alguns issues do git deles, aparentemente é erro deles mesmo tanto que abandonei e utilizei a chamada direta para a api do google

Answer (score 1):

O problema está no seu `componentDidMount`, o `getCurrentPosition` é uma função assíncrona, então quando você chama o `Geocoder.geocodePosition` no seu state latitude e longitude ainda são `null`. Tente colocar o `Geocoder.geocodePosition` dentro do `getCurrentPosition` como abaixo:

```
componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
         Geocoder.geocodePosition( { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude})
          .then(res => {
              this.setState({
                  place: res[0].formatedAddress
              });
          });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );

  }
```

Comment: Testei aqui: https://snack.expo.io/Hywmw03TZ mas continua sem retornar o endereço

Comment: Desculpa, erro meu. Eu editei a chamada para `Geocoder.geocodePosition( position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)`

Comment: Pergunta importante, você está usando Build com código nativo ou o create-react-native-app do react-native? O Geocoder tem dependências nativas que precisam ser 'linkadas' no projeto.

Comment: Criei o projeto com o `react-native init` adicionei o `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` ao `AndroidManifest.xml` e utilizei o `react-native link` para 'linkar' o projeto

Comment: Já mexi bastante no projeto e estou atualmente com este código: https://snack.expo.io/r18t-A3pb

Comment: Mas ainda não consegui fazer retornar o endereço

Comment: Fiz umas modificações no seu código deixando [assim](https://snack.expo.io/Hyx8dMaaW).  Uma pergunta, você já tentou passar uma localização fixa no geocoder para verificar se o problema não está na configuração da lib?

Comment: Tentei sim e recebo o mesmo erro que estou recebendo agora `Cannot read property 'geocodePosition' of undefined` até abri um `issue` no repositório da lib pra ver se obtenho alguma ajuda lá: https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder/issues/62

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67642/discussion-between-lucas-santana-and-mateus).